# Equivalent of Openssl RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING in IPhone Security framework and common crypto libraries

Tags: iphone, xcode, openssl, rsa, padding

I am trying to convert code written in Openssl into the iphone’s built in security framework and crypto libraries. Is there an equivalent padding value RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING in the built in apple functions? Is there a value I can hardcode for my padding variable to get the same value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around the padding issue by being able to incorporate Openssl so I don't have to use the crypto libraries.